# Printing a wreq response to the terminal

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to do something very simple; make a `wreq` response and print the contents to the terminal.

main.hs looks like this:
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

```
module Main where

import Network.Wreq
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

main :: IO ()
main = do
  r <- get "http://httpbin.org/get"
  putStrLn (C.unpack r)
```

Why?  Because `r` seems to be a bytestring, so it should be unpackable.

```
Prelude> import Network.Wreq
Prelude Network.Wreq> r <- get "http://httpbin.org/get"
Prelude Network.Wreq> :type r
r :: Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
```

My .cabal file looks like this:

```
executable wreqscraper
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       wreq,
                       bytestring
```

And when I try to build it with `stack build` I get this:

```
/Users/mkaravan/end2end/haskell_sandbox/wreqscraper/src/Main.hs:22:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘C.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘Response
                                      Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
    • In the first argument of ‘C.unpack’, namely ‘r’
      In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(C.unpack r)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (C.unpack r)
```

What is the correct way to print these contents with `putStrLn` (or something similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unwrap the `Response ByteString`, so you get a `ByteString` and you can use it with `C.unpack`.

Here is a working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C

main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- get "http://httpbin.org/get"
    Prelude.putStrLn $ C.unpack $ (r ^. responseBody)
```